# Crear un archivo a partir de un OracleBFile

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-11g, odp.net

Tengo archivos guardados en mi base de datos Oracle con campo `BFile`. Hago un `select` y obtengo ese campo `BFile`. Pero ahora tengo dudas sobre cómo obtener ese arreglo de bytes, recuperar el archivo almacenado y guardarlo en `C:\`.

Estos son mis avances:

```
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("SELECT IMG FROM IMAGES WHERE ID='" + idText + "'", conn2); 
OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
using (reader)
{
    if (reader.Read())
    {

        OracleBFile bFile = reader.GetOracleBFile(0);
         byte[] buffer = new byte[bFile.Length];
         using (bFile)
         {
             bFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
             bFile.Write(buffer, 0, 100);
         }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando tu ejemplo, digamos que quieres almacenar el contenido del `BFILE` hacia `c:\test\archivo.dat`, esta sería una manera sencilla de lograrlo:

```
using (var bFile = reader.GetOracleBFile(0))
{
    bFile.OpenFile();

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\test\archivo.dat", FileMode.Create))
    {
        bFile.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
```

**Nota adicional**: Te sugiero que la instancia de `OracleCommand` acepte `idText` como un parámetro mas bien que concatenarlo directamente en tu sentencia SQL.  Desarollar esa buena costumbre te va a evitar muchos problemas.